# How to truncate the result of a division in intersystems cache?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I want to get the truncated integer.

E.g in doing this division: 5/3,
I want the result to be 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I'm looking now really silly, because I didn't read original question, but will answer now to the *original* question]

If you want to do integer division in COS you need to use [*integer division* \ operator](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RBAS_ointdiv)

`write 5\3`

/ operator will always do *float point division* (unless you are in Corba language mode. Don't ask what it is)

Comment: Yes this looks like the most concise way. I find it quite weird that the docs don't state if this integer division result is rounded or truncated...

Answer (score 0):

simple way to do it, is using [$piece](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fpiece)

```
write $piece(5/3,".",1)
1
```

or with getting decimal separator

```
set  decimalSeparator=##class(%SYS.NLS.Format).GetFormatItem("DecimalSeparator")
write $piece(5/3,decimalSeparator,1)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `$fnumber` function which could drop floating part, the trick is to left numeric without any extra formatting, and for this you could use `""` as format specifier.

```
write $fnumber(5/3,"",0)
2
```

Comment: I get a weird result with this: write $fnumber(14/3,"",0) -> 5 is printed instead of 4. How do you explain it?

Comment: @syonip Well, goot point - it does rounding here, instead of truncation. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use [$System.SQL.Floor](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYSTEM.SQL#METHOD_FLOOR)

> classmethod FLOOR(val As %Library.Numeric = "") as %Library.Integer
>
> FLOOR is a numeric function that returns the largest integer less than or
> equal to a given numeric expression
>
> $SYSTEM.SQL.FLOOR(numeric-exp)
>
> numeric-exp
>
> A number whose floor is to be calculated.

I haven't done any performance testing or anything, but that seems to be exactly what you're looking for.